# Is there a way to reveal invisible characters in Awesomenauts?

Tags: awesomenauts

Some characters in Awesomenauts can become invisible. Is there a way to see them until they actually go out of stealth from their own decision? So far, the only way I see is to actually bump physically into one, because it blocks you.

Is there a skill from one of the characters, or something to do to reveal an invisible player?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**: The 1.03 patch for the PC version has added a new character, Gnaw, who has an attack called [Acid Spit](http://awesomenauts.wikia.com/wiki/Acid_Spit) which makes it possible to track enemies while they are cloaked (though it doesn't remove the cloak effect itself). If you watch this [Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9NzRgM_leM&t=13m56s) of Bunnymancer playing Gnaw, you'll see him hitting an enemy Leon with Acid Spit and tracking him even though he is cloaked.

**Original Answer**: No, there is no way to reveal invisible enemy players.

Currently, Leon's Cloaking Skin is the only ability that allows players to become hidden from the opposite team, and the only way to end the effect is for the invisible player to take an action other than moving or jumping.

The invisible Leon will still take damage if hit by attacks, but this will not remove the invisibility.

Comment: A bit outdated, there are now plenty of effects that show his location.

Comment: @Sentry Thanks for letting me know. I haven't played Awesomenauts in quite a while, so I made my answer into a wiki. Feel free to update it with some more up-to-date information :-)

Answer (score 7):

There is a passive way of doing this - by affecting Leon with poisoning, slowing or some other effect that shows some thumbnail above character.

There is also a neat trick usable at AL Station 404. Between the front turret and the top turret behind there is an area with yellow floor that lights up when you step on it. It actually saved me once or twice because I could see invisible Leon approaching me by looking at the floor lighting.

Upd1: another trick, barely usable though. Invisible characters still collect solar 8p. So, if there is solar lying around, you might notice invisible's presence.

Comment: When you snipe with Raelynn and Leon is in the line of sight, he has a crosshair symbol over it and the laser turns from blue to yellow. I also often buy the Blind upgrade so he is marked longer by the "blinded" icon.

Answer (score -2):

if you turn off music and/or concentrate on the sound effects, actually you can also predict a leon by *hearing his footsteps*.